# Why is my use of JSON Schema `allOf` keyword not validating correctly?

Tags: json, jsonschema, xapi

I am running into more children objects that are not validating correctly (object.actor, object.verb, object.object).  I tried looking for any empty schema after changing my if/then structures in the object schema to if/then/else adding the false value for each else.  I did not find anything obvious.

JSON -Should fail but doesn't

```
{
  "actor": {
    "objectType": "Agent",
    "name": "xAPI account",
    "mbox": "mailto:xapi@adlnet.gov"
  },
  "verb": {
    "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/attended",
    "display": {
      "en-GB": "attended",
      "en-US": "attended"
    }
  },
  "object": {

    "objectType": "SubStatement",
    "actor": {
      "objectType": "should fail",
      "name": "xAPI mbox",
      "mbox": "mailto:should fail"
    },
    "verb": {
      "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/reported",
      "display": {
        "should fail": "reported",
        "en-US": "reported"
      }
    },
    "object": {
      "objectType": "Activity",
      "id": "should fail"
    }
  }
}
```

JSON - Fails at the root level only; substatement values are not checked.  assuming empty schema coming from somewhere.

```
{
  "actor": {
    "objectType": "Agent",
    "name": "xAPI account",
    "mbox": "this fails"
  },
  "verb": {
    "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/attended",
    "display": {
      "this fails": "attended",
      "en-US": "attended"
    }
  },
  "object": {

    "objectType": "SubStatement",
    "actor": {
      "objectType": "should fail",
      "name": "xAPI mbox",
      "mbox": "mailto:should fail"
    },
    "verb": {
      "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/reported",
      "display": {
        "should fail": "reported",
        "en-US": "reported"
      }
    },
    "object": {
      "objectType": "Activity",
      "id": "should fail"
    }
  }
}
```

JSON SCHEMA (stripped to the bone)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "xAPIValidator",
  "description": "Validation schema for xAPI tests",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Statement"
    },
    {
      "statements": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Statement"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "Statement": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "objectType": {
          "type:": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Agent",
            "Activity",
            "Group",
            "SubStatement",
            "StatementRef"
          ]
        },
        "id": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/uuid"
            }
          ]
        },
        "actor": {
          "$id": "#actor",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
            }
          ]
        },
        "verb": {
          "$id": "#verb",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
                }
              ]
            },
            "display": {
              "type": "object",
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/lang5646"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "object": {
          "$id": "#object",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "objectType": {
              "type:": "string",
              "enum": [
                "Activity",
                "Agent",
                "Group",
                "SubStatement",
                "StatementRef"
              ]
            }
          },
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "if": {
                "properties": {
                  "objectType": {
                    "const": "SubStatement"
                  }
                }
              },
              "then": {
                "$comment": "Substatement object type",
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Statement"
                  }
                ],
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "required": [
                        "id"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "required": [
                        "authority"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "required": [
                        "stored"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {"required":["actor","verb","object"]}
                ]
              },
              "else": false
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "actor",
        "verb",
        "object"
      ]
    },
    "Agent": {
      "$id": "#Agent",
      "maxProperties": 3,
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/IFI"
        }
      ]
    },
    "AnonGroup": {
      "$id": "#AnonGroup",
      "maxProperties": 3,
      "properties": {
        "member": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "objectType": [
          "member"
        ]
      },
      "required": [
        "member"
      ],
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "mbox"
        ]
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "mbox_sha1sum"
        ]
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "openid"
        ]
      },
      "not": {
        "required": [
          "account"
        ]
      }
    },
    "IdGroup": {
      "$id": "#IdGroup",
      "maxProperties": 4,
      "properties": {
        "member": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/allOfAgentGroup"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/IFI"
        }
      ]
    },
    "allOfAgentGroup": {
      "properties": {
        "objectType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Agent",
            "Group"
          ]
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "objectType": {
                "const": "Agent"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Agent"
              }
            ]
          },
          "else": false
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "objectType": {
                "const": "Group"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/IdGroup"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/AnonGroup"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "else": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "IFI": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "mbox": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/mailto"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "mbox"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "mbox_sha1sum": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "\\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\\b"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "mbox_sha1sum"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "account": {
              "properties": {
                "homePage": {
                  "allOf": [
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "homePage",
                "name"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "account"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "openid": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/URI"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "openid"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "mailto": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "(mailto:)(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"
    },
    "URI": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]"
    },
    "uuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$"
    },
    "lang5646": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^((?:(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)|(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang))|((?:([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-(?:[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})(-(?:[A-Za-z]{4}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(-(?:[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*(-(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?)|(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))$": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "lang5646string": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^((?:(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)|(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang))|((?:([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-(?:[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})(-(?:[A-Za-z]{4}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(-(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(-(?:[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*(-(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?)|(?:x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))$"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't get your SCHEMA to validate. Have you checked it against https://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-07/markup/json ?

Comment: You don't have a validated JSON.

Comment: Apparently the validator I was using was a bit more lenient.  There was an extra comma at the end.  I've fixed the schema above.

Comment: Please provide JSON you expect to pass and that you expect to fail, and explain why it should fail. Currently I don’t have enough information in your question to help you.

Comment: It looks like you can probably strip down your schema (for the purpose of debugging) further. It looks like specific field definitions like timestamp can just be `"timestamp": true` under properties. I tried to debug the issue by guessing what you might want, but I still do not know =]

Comment: @Relequestual I have added "should fail" in fields that should fail.  I have also added a separate JSON sample that fails at the root level. What the spec calls for is a statement with at a minimum actor, verb and object properties.  The object property can also be a statement (substatement) with its own actor, verb, and object props.  The JSON should fail for the items in the substatement but they are not.

Comment: @Relequestual I'll strip down the schema down to the bones and add that in a bit.

Comment: Super. I've tried to strip it down, but maybe you can too =]

Comment: @Relequestual Wait a bit before looking at it further.  I pulled down the original schema from above and it wasn't working at all.  I'll edit the schema as soon as i can.

Comment: Schema stripped to the bone and is above now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `"$id": "#object"` > oneOf > then, you define `allOf` twice in that JSON object.

The behaviour of duplicate keys in JSON is undefined.
Often the way it's handled is just to take the last occurrence of each key for an object.

You can see this working by having the following schema and an empty object instance: `{}`

Schema :

```
{
  "allOf": [
    false
  ],
  "allOf": [
    true
  ]
}
```

The JSON library will likely ignore the first `allOf`, taking the last occurrence, resulting in allways pass validation. Swap the `true` and `false` to double confirm.

Any time you've used a specific `*of` keyword more than once in the same object in the schema (or any key more than once in an object), you'll need to fix it.

Comment: This worked. Changed one of them to oneOf and things started working correctly.  Adding this bit of info to my schema debugging tools.  Thanks!! :)

Comment: Given it was an "allOf", you could have combined them, making one "allOf" as opposed to two.

Comment: Would be interested to hear all your debugging tools. I'm creating JSON Schema Lint soon. You can reach me on the JSON Schema slack! =]